# Consume keystroke in autohotkey (don't let it propagate to other apps)

Tags: autohotkey

I have a problem have a keystorke set in autohotkey, but teh problem is that one program running on background consumes that keystroke and autohotkey action doenn't trigger at all. I need autohotkey to consume that keystorke first and don't let it get away so other application doesn't notice it ever happened.

Edit:

```
!t::
send {up}
return
```

This works just fine without background program running (Taskbar Eliminator)

Comment: Can you add (using the `edit` link) the snippet you're using?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx - what makes you think that application wouldn't do the same thing? You can't both be unstoppable forces. FWIW, in this case, the last application to register that hotkey should take control of it, so either remap the hotkey in one of the applications or figure out how to get your autohotkey script to load last.

Comment: Just running autohotkey last should do it I think (assuming it registers the hotkey on startup of the program).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a '$' in front of your hotkey. Like this:

```
$!t::
send {up}
return
```

Otherwise to make your script be the last to register the hotkey, you can make it restart after a few seconds like this:

```
Sleep, 5000 ; 5 secs
Reload
```