# How to influence which background application consumes keystroke on Windows (7, Vista)

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any way to influence which application on Windows consumes keystrokes first?

My problem is that I have two applications running in background. The application that is not that important eats a keystroke, so the second application does nothing in the end.

Is there any way to affect this behavior?

Comment: Which keystrokes and which applications are you talking about? I know you're asking a general question, but maybe there's an easy solution for your special case.

Comment: Autohotkey - I want every keystroke to be handled by ahk before any other application gets the chance.

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect that!

Comment: Seems like http://superuser.com/questions/291018/consume-keystroke-in-autohotkey-dont-let-it-propagate-to-other-apps to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your OS?

You can use autohotkey to do this with XP and probably vista and 7:

Check out http://www.autohotkey.com/

And

http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic2270.html

Comment: Actually, autohotkey is that program I want to intercept all my keystrokes first, the problem is that second program intercepts them before that.